# saving spinner state using sharedpreferences in android

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I am developing an android app which gives access to a form via a login screen
If user gets interrupted he can go back to the form via login screen
To avoid effort by user I am implementing a SAVE button

I am saving the editText fields by using shared preferences with putstring class

How can I save the state of the  SPINNERS using shared preferences?

Please help me out

Comment: I'm not trying to knock you or anything, but what does the save button do? If the user gets interrupted, they can't click save.

Comment: ADDENDUM: You should instead Override the onPause method and do your saving there.

Comment: It is not only for interruption but also when the user opens the app next time he have most of the form filled and only he has to change a few parameters to submit it again . I want to decrease the burden of filling the same data again yet provide the flexibility to change if needed :-)

Comment: You can still do that onPause/onStop. Completely remove the user from having to click anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();` that will return to you an int that you can save with `prefEdit.putInt();` then when you want to re-load everything that has been saved you would just call `spinner.setSelection(prefs.getInt("key", default));`